# Xcode style toolbar SwiftUI for macOS

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, toolbar, nstoolbar

I am contributing to a project called CodeEdit, which is looking to make a code editor with a design similar to Xcode. In dark mode, I can't get the toolbar color to be the same as the toolbar in Xcode dark mode, it is always black in dark mode. The video below shows what is happening. All code is in https://github.com/highjeans/CodeEdit. I looked at [Customizing the macOS toolbar with Swift UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70161675/customizing-the-macos-toolbar-with-swift-ui) but that is not what I need. I also looked at [SwiftUI macOS Xcode Style Toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65454903/swiftui-macos-xcode-style-toolbar) but that is more for something similar to Notes not Xcode.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/185LQCeiVwSub8GIj19f6svUTHa7hsBCL/view?usp=sharing

Edit: I got the color to work, I don't know how to change the white background under the Tab Bar: [Picture of sort of working toolbar color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8K5d.png)

Answer (score 2):

I got it working by changing the most random line ever. If you are looking for a toolbar color similar to Xcode, change NSWindow.titlebarSeparatorStyle to .line.